# How to get the value from a Nested JSON object from a JSON file using Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript, nested

I am new to Typescript. I am trying to iterate a nested JSON file that has segments and products. From the product's value trying to store it and display it on the console.

JSON File :

```
{
    "int": {
        "name": "internal",
        "products": {
            "test": "Internal Test from Actions"
        }
    },
    "tst": {
        "name": "test",
        "products": {
            "action": "Test Actions"
        }
    }
}
```

From the above example I am trying to parse the JSON with *value* "Test Actions" and get the *key* `action` and store it as a string.

Basically the typescript needs to iterate through the products and find the **value** if it is found then get the **key** and store it in a string.

Comment: Well you can do it by using `Object.keys` if you need to iterate over key and values. You can then do it recursively if you need to dive into an item which is non native type. Can you post what you have tried ?

Comment: I am not sure as how to use it. can you please provide an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to get the key and value.

```
const printKeyAndValue = (objVal: any) => {
  for (const key of Object.keys(objVal)){
      console.log(key);
      console.log(objVal[key]);   
  }
};

const obj = {
  'item1': 123,
  'item2': 'some string value'
};

printKeyAndValue(obj);
```

Please note the sample I have provided is an object with primitive types only and only top level properties. If you have a nested structure, you must handle accordingly.

Comment: Thank you :). I will try to implement as per my requirement.

Comment: Sure. Good luck. And if it’s helps to arrive at solution, please remember to mark as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Below is the Output I am getting. I want the value "Test Actions" and get the key "action" to be printed separately. 

<[LOG]: "int" 
[LOG]: {
  "name": "internal",
  "products": {
    "test": "Internal Test from Actions"
  }
} 
[LOG]: "tst" 
[LOG]: {
  "name": "test",
  "products": {
    "action": "Test Actions"
  }
} >

Comment: Well like I said, for complex properties, you'd have to recursivesly call this or you can pass that specific property. Something like `printKeyAndValue(data.int.products)`